# How to create this right Arrow with different background in footer with social icons on top

Tags: html, css

This is the output needed :
http://awesomescreenshot.com/0423rum638

I have created the social icons and for the arrow with different colour i assigned two div's and made one float left and another float right and gave it different background but i dont know how to make the arrow appear.
This is what i have got now 
http://awesomescreenshot.com/0983rum825

I know how to add an arrow but i am not getting the background like that. 
Here is the code

```
<div class="social-icons-container">
            <div class="social-icons">
                <div class="solid-container">
</div>
<div class="social-icons-img">
<ul>
<li><a href="www.facebook.com"><img src="http://www./wp-content/thesis/skins/cinch/images/facebook.png"></a></li>
<li><a href="www.google-plus.com"><img src="http://wp-content/thesis/skins/cinch/images/google.png"></a></li>
<li><a href="www.youtube.com"><img src="http:///wp-content/thesis/skins/cinch/images/youtube.png"></a></li>
<li><a href="www.pinterest.com"><img src="http:///wp-content/thesis/skins/cinch/images/pinterest.png"></a></li>
<li><a href="www.twitter.com"><img src="http:///wp-content/thesis/skins/cinch/images/twitter.png"></a></li>
<li><a href="www.linkedin.com"><img src="http:///wp-content/thesis/skins/cinch/images/linkedin.png"></a></li>
<li><a href="www.rss.com"><img src="http://www./wp-content/thesis/skins/cinch/images/rss.png"></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
            </div>
        </div>


css :
.social-icons-img {
width: 65%;
float: right;
}

.social-icons-container {
background-color: #36375c;
}
.solid-container {
width: 30%;
background-image: none;
padding: 35px 0;
padding-bottom: 20px;
float: left;
background-color: grey;
}
```

Comment: Please show your code. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my simple arrow demo: http://jsfiddle.net/abruzzi/cao26oao/
To make an arrow with css, you can use code like below:

```
<div class="arrow"></div>

.arrow {
    border: 10px solid transparent;
    border-left-color: black;
}
```

#### Update:

Here's an accomplished arrow demo for your question: 
http://jsfiddle.net/abruzzi/cao26oao/1/
and code below:

Html

```
<footer></footer>
```

CSS

```
footer {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #37375D;
}
footer:before {
    display: block;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #46475C;
}
footer:after {
    display: block;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    height: 0px;
    width: 0px;
    border: 25px solid transparent;
    border-left-color: #46475C;
}
```

#### Update Latest:

Look this, which is your truly need:
http://jsfiddle.net/abruzzi/cao26oao/2/

Comment: yes i know to add the triangle but how to add it like in the output needed with a background change. I have added my codes

Comment: Great. But i have to add social icons to the right of it like here http://awesomescreenshot.com/0423rum638 . Where Should i add the social media icons code ?

Answer (score 0):

**Fiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/pmyLv/60/

HTML

```
<div class="footer">
    <span class="foreground">
        <i class="fa fa-round fa-facebook"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-round fa-twitter"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-round fa-youtube"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-round fa-linkedin"></i>
    </span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
    .foreground{
    z-index:4;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    margin-left:35%;

}
.footer {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #37375D;
}
.footer:before {
    display: block;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 30%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #46475C;
}
.footer:after {
    display: block;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 30%;
    height: 0px;
    width: 0px;
    border: 25px solid transparent;
    border-left-color: #46475C;
}

.arrow {
    border: 10px solid transparent;
    border-left-color: black;
}


.footer{
    background:
}

.fa-round {
    padding: 0;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color: white;
    background-color: #40cdda;
    font-size: 1.30em;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    height: 1.5em;
    width: 1.5em;
    text-align:center;
    border: solid 1px white;
    margin-top:8px;

}
.fa-round:hover {
    background:#37375D;
    opacity:0.9;

}

.fa-facebook {
    background-color: #3b5998;
    margin-right: 4px;
}

.fa-twitter {
    background-color: #40cdda;
    margin-right: 4px;
}

.fa-youtube {
    background-color: #ff3132;
    margin-right: 4px;
}

.fa-linkedin {
    background-color: #0073b2;
}
```